# angular 2 animation group bug apply only 2 last animation

Tags: angular2-animation

I'm trying to animate a button on X and Y directions , by 4 steps with different timing configurations, with group animation, but find out that only the last two animation works! it ignores the first 2 animations.
why that happening? I'm doing anything wrong?
Thanks!

component code:

```
 <button [@myAnimate]="myState"
        (click)="updateMyState()">
    myTransfrom
</button>
```

ts code:

```
animations: [
        trigger('myAnimate', [
            state('first', style({ color: 'blue' })),
            state('second', style({ color: 'red' })),
            transition('first <=> second',
                [
                group([
                        animate('1s ease', style({
                            transform: 'translateX(0%) translateY(100%)' 
                        }))
                        , animate('1s 1s ease', style({
                            transform: 'translateX(-100%) translateY(100%)'
                    }))
                        , animate('1s 2s ease', style({
                            transform: 'translateX(100%) translateY(100%)'
                        }))
                        , animate('1s 3s ease', style({
                            transform: 'translateX(0%) translateY(100%)'
                    }))
                        , animate('1s 4s ease', style({
                            transform: 'translateX(0%) translateY(200%)'
                    }))
            ])
            ]
    )])]
```